# R mice: Specifying maximum number of predictors using quickpred

Tags: r, r-mice

I have found the `quickpred` function in `mice` useful in providing some guidance re: choosing variables to use as predictors in the multiple imputation process. I recently came across a scenario where `quickpred` reduced the number of predictors for a given outcome to 800+ variables. Out of curiosity, is it possible to specify the maximum number of predictors (say 15) per outcome chosen by the function?

**For example:**

From the `mice` package help files,

```
df <- mice::nhanes

# default: include all predictors with absolute correlation over 0.1
quickpred(df)

# all predictors with absolute correlation over 0.4
quickpred(df, mincor=0.4)

# include age and bmi, exclude chl
quickpred(nhanes, mincor=0.4, inc=c('age','bmi'), exc='chl')

# only include predictors with at least 30% usable cases
quickpred(nhanes, minpuc=0.3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update based on extra information in comments**

How about this approach then. Run through a grid of correlations - compute the number of predictors per *row* and then feed `quickpred` individual correlations to reflect a threshold requirement.

For 1 or less predictors per prediction (change `x<=1` to modify that):

```
grid <- seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.05)
result <- apply(sapply(grid, function(x) { rowSums(quickpred(df, mincor=x)) } ), 1, function(x) {min(which(x<=1))})
result
age bmi hyp chl 
  1   7   8   8
```

So use the first correlation from `grid` for variable 1, Number 7 from variable 2 etc.

This can be inserted directly in `quickpred`

```
> quickpred(df, mincor=grid[result])
    age bmi hyp chl
age   0   0   0   0
bmi   0   0   0   0
hyp   1   0   0   0
chl   1   0   0   0
```

where we have at most 1 predictor per variable. If we want 3 or less predictors we get

```
> quickpred(df, mincor=grid[result])
    age bmi hyp chl
age   0   0   0   0
bmi   1   0   1   1
hyp   1   0   0   1
chl   1   1   1   0
```

**Original answer**

You can probably fix that by computing the number of parameters yourself and then select the cut-off that gives you the desired number of predictors.

For example, if I go through correlations defined by `seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.05)`, compute the column sums of the corresponding binary `quickpred` prediction matrix (to get information about which columns/variables are included in the prediction somewhere), and then count the number of columns that are non-zero I use the following code

```
grid <- seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.05)
result <- sapply(grid, function(x) { sum(colSums(quickpred(df, mincor=x))>0) } )
```

which produces

```
> result
[1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 1 1
```

Say I only wanted 1 predictor in my model. I would then have to use a minimum absolute correlation of 0.45 (=`grid[min(which(result <= 1))]`) since that is the first time my prediction matrix ends up with one predictor (from this grid anyway).

```
> quickpred(df, mincor=.45)
    age bmi hyp chl
age   0   0   0   0
bmi   0   0   0   0
hyp   1   0   0   0
chl   1   0   0   0
```

So `age` is the predictor. And with `mincor=.4` I get

```
> quickpred(df, mincor=.40)
    age bmi hyp chl
age   0   0   0   0
bmi   0   0   0   0
hyp   1   0   0   1
chl   1   0   1   0
```

which involves 3 predictors.

Comment: Works well. Unfortunately, I should have specified further - I am looking to specify the maximum number of predictors per outcome. Say I want 15 predictors per outcome; the predictors do not need to be the same across outcomes. Is this possible?